# Catch 22 in Python while trying to start a FLASK app with Gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I need to use Gunicorn to run a Flask app, yet Gunicorn doesn't read this part of the code if **name** == '**main**':

```
import sys
#...

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all routes


@app.route('/api/myapi', methods=['POST'])
def myapi():

#...


@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
return response


#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    print('Starting APP server...')
#    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
#    context.load_cert_chain('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/cert.pem',
#                           '/etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem')
#    app.run(host='mywebsite.com', port=5000, ssl_context=context)
```

If I uncommented the "if **name** == '**main**':" then I have a development FLASK app and it works like a charm, but that's not the idea so I'm using Gunicorn with a separated file called wsgi.py

```
from vicky_server_ionos_8 import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And then

```
gunicorn --bind 88.888.888.888:5000 wsgi:app
```

So here's the catch 22...to not run the app in a developement way...I need to use Gunicorn...yet Gunicorm seems to ignore this if **name** == '**main**': so the script never hits app.run() so the app never runs.

I thought that Gunicorn does that automaticly, yep no...the app never starts because Guarnicon seems to ignore the very part that runs the app...

What could be the issue or any ideas how to use correctly Gunicorn?

Comment: Just run `gunicorn ... vicky_server_ionos_8:app` then.

Comment: Since vicky_server_ionos_8 has no app.run, then the app never starts. I've heard that that is the purpose of Gunicorn, yet the app never starts withput app.run, that Gunicorn doesn't understand

Comment: `app.run()` starts the built-in dev server for a Flask app. Since `app` is a WSGI app, you should be able to run Gunicorn like that (so Gunicorn is the server for the app). What does `gunicorn` say when you try that?

Answer (score 2):

If I assume that all your code is in a single module (single file), named for example `my_file.py`, here is how to execute it with `gunicorn`:

```
gunicorn -b 88.888.888.888:5000 my_file:app
```

As the [gunicorn documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html) indicates, the syntax follows the following pattern:

```
$ gunicorn [OPTIONS] [WSGI_APP]
```

Where `WSGI_APP` is of the pattern `$(MODULE_NAME):$(VARIABLE_NAME)`.
In your case it is the name of your module (your file) and the global variable `app` which creates a Flask application object — app — in the current Python module.

Comment: It's always the same...if I put a message at the end of the py file, as example
print('This is the last thing that Gunicorn does')...then If I run Gunicorn I see the message there...yet never the message that the app started. Once it reached that message at the end of the file, thats it...it never invokes the method app.run()...so the app never starts

Comment: @Diego The purpose of this instruction `if __name__ == '__main__':` is to make sure the server only runs if the script is executed directly from the Python interpreter and not used as an imported module. Gunicorn does not need this statement to run your script. Gunicorn won't even execute the code that comes after this statement.

You say that when you run gunicorn you see a message. Can you show us what the gunicorn command displays in your console and how you execute it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the right way to do it.
Explanation: I was working with Gunicorn yet the best way to go is Gunicorn3 in my case. Then I just forgot to add the SSL certificates so the app was serving on http, so the client side would never allowed such connection.

Solution:

```
gunicorn3 --workers=3 --bind 88.888.888.888:5000 --certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/cert.pem --keyfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem vicky_server_ionos_8:app
```

Thanks for the help and hope it helps as well.
Greetings.